# HTML5 Duplicate lists <ul> <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to make several copies of a list, around ten. The list is like:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I make a x10 duplication without writing the code 10 times? Because the items "1", "2" etc. will link the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mj0qyyd/)):
**html**:

```
<div id = "list">    
   <!-- to be populated using jquery-->
</div>
```

**js**:

```
var listContainer = $("#list")
for(i=0; i<10; ++i){
        listContainer.append( $("<nav><ul> <li>1</li> <li>2</li> <li>3</li> <li>4</li> <li>5</li> <li>6</li> <li>7</li> <li>8</li> <li>9</li> <li>10</li></ul>"))    
        console.log("adding...")
    }
```

Comment: bad quality code. You don't need to wrap '<nav> ...' in jQuery object, not saying that it would be just easier to copy already existing html, and last thing is that jQuery here is a little bit of overhead (also you are not specifying that you use it )

Answer (score 3):

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    ul = document.createElement('ul'),
    li,
    i;
for (i = 10; i--;) {  //the way this loop works, will add the elements in reverse order. Order could be of importance to you, so just an FYI
    li = document.createElement('li');
    //do some stuff to li here
    fragment.appendChild(li);
}
ul.appendChild(fragment);
```

No JQuery, just ~10 lines

Reference for `fragment`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

**EDIT**

For the case you want to iterate upon the whole `ul` and not the `li` as I understood:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul'),
    container = /*the container DOM element of the <ul>*/,
    liFragment
    ulFragment;

function create(tag, times) {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        el;

    for (times; times--;) {  
        el = document.createElement(tag);
        //do some stuff to the element here
        fragment.appendChild(el);
    }
    return fragment;
}

function clone(element, times, deep) {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        deep = (typeof deep === 'boolean') ? deep : true;
        el;

    for (times; times--;) {  
        el = element.cloneNode(deep);
        //do some stuff to the element here
        fragment.appendChild(el);
    }
    return fragment;
}

liFragment = create('li', 10);
ul.appendChild(liFragment);
ulFragment = clone(ul, 10);

container.appendChild(ulFragment);
```

Comment: You can speed it up with `createDocumentFragment` as it will not have to redraw on every appendChild. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

Comment: Also I think he meant whole list not only li, but this same concept

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki you think it's a more complete answer now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method in jQuery to do this pretty simply.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  $('#target').append($('#copied').clone());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <nav id="copied">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! but, how can I apply this for make it work? on a new file .js, Have I to create a new function and put this code inside for do this?